# populating a dropdown from data in the database

Tags: javascript

I have the following.
HTML

```
 <div class="frmInput">
                        <select id="registrationTypeDropDown" class="select">
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Javascript

```
fetch('../svc/RegistrationForm.asmx/GetRegistrationType', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then((response) => {
    types = response.json();
    
    for (const [ID, Name] of Object.entries(types)) {
        console.log(ID, Name);
        options += '<option value="' + ID + '" text="' + Name + '" />';
    }
    $('#registrationTypeDropDown').append(options);
  });
```

I've tried different ways of getting my results and nothing is working.  When I run it it doesn't even hit my for loop.  I'd appreciate it if someone can point out a better way of doing this or what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting a response?

Comment: Yes I am getting a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually assigning `Promise` to the `types` variable try this. Also see [using fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
fetch('../svc/RegistrationForm.asmx/GetRegistrationType', {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(response => response.json()). // you are missing this line
then((response) => {
  types = response;

  for (const [ID, Name] of Object.entries(types)) {
    console.log(ID, Name);
    options += '<option value="' + ID + '" text="' + Name + '" />';
  }
  $('#registrationTypeDropDown').append(options);
});
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed the the issue getting values in the variable types but the Name constant in the for loop is defined as the array.  How do I get the values from it.

Comment: Can you post the response ??

Comment: I just posted the image from chrome dev tools in the original post.  You see d is the ID const and Name is the Array.

Comment: its tough to figure out like this can you post the data ,it would be verry easier

Comment: idRegistrationType registrationType
23 Reseller
24 Guest